# PDF not working with List Int array passed to Browser

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, pdf

Hi I have a defined variable contentAll from where I am writing to server as a PDF and mailing it to users. They want to see it open in a browser.

Server C# code is as below

```
List<int> contentAll = new List<int>();
contentAll = [01,02, 03,.....] etc. - Just a sample

byte[] base64EncodedStringBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(contentAll.SelectMany<int, byte>(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray()));
return Ok(base64EncodedStringBytes);
```

Jquery Code is as below

```
var pdfWin = window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + response, "_blank", 'height=650,width=840');
```

Where response is the returned `base64EncodedStringBytes`

I am able to write the PDF and send it so no issues with content.

However Chrome is not opening it. [The Error in PDF window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWeid.png) . Can someone assist

Comment: Usually, there’s no space after `base64,` in a `data:` URL.

Comment: Tried that too .. its not working

Comment: if you decode the string shown in the error using javascripts `atob`, **and decode the decoded string** again with `atob`, you end up with the following string of characters (ignore the spaces in the following, it's just to make it CLEAR) `% 0x00 0x00 0x00 P 0x00 0x00 0x00 D 0x00 0x00 0x00 F 0x00 0x00 0x00` etc ... you should be able to figure out what you're doing wrong from this information ... note 0x00 is null character